# 2d array of generic length in a class

Tags: vb.net

I have a class that currently works like this.

```
Class Maze
    Public board(10, 10) As Object 
Dim maze1 As New Maze With {.board = {{" ", " ", "X", "X", " ", "X", "X", "X", " ", "X"},
                                      {"X", " ", " ", " ", " ", "X", " ", " ", " ", "X"},
                                      {" ", " ", "X", " ", "X", " ", " ", " ", " ", "X"},
                                      {"X", " ", "X", " ", " ", "X", "X", "X", " ", " "},
                                      {"X", " ", "X", "X", " ", " ", " ", " ", "X", " "},
                                      {" ", "X", " ", " ", "X", " ", " ", "X", " ", " "},
                                      {" ", "X", "X", " ", "X", " ", " ", " ", " ", "X"},
                                      {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "X", "X", " ", " ", "X"},
                                      {"X", "X", " ", "X", " ", " ", " ", "X", " ", " "},
                                      {" ", " ", " ", "X", "X", " ", " ", " ", "X", " "}}}
```

However I cant find away to remove the prespecified length without methods such as GetLength now not working.

Comment: You should be able to inspect the size of an array at runtime, as long as it isn't null (`Nothing`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This allows you to have 2d array without specifying length explicitly

```
Public board(,) As Object = {}
```

Comment: Whenever you define a variable as `Object` in .Net, you're almost certainly making a huge mistake you will soon come to regret. Also, that code _does_ specify an explicit length: 0 by 0.

Answer (score 1):

In the .Net world, if you define a type as `Object` you're almost always doing something very wrong you will soon come to regret. In this case, it looks like `String` may be more appropriate. However, perhaps based on how this is used later it might turn out that Integer or a specific class type could be better, alongside a special method to translate this into text or graphics for output.

Moving on to the specific issue of size... consider a List:

```
Class Maze
        Dim board As List(Of List(Of String))
        

board = New List(Of List(Of string)) From {
            New List(Of String) From {" ", " ", "X", "X", " ", "X", "X", "X", " ", "X"},
            New List(Of String) From {"X", " ", " ", " ", " ", "X", " ", " ", " ", "X"},
            New List(Of String) From {" ", " ", "X", " ", "X", " ", " ", " ", " ", "X"},
            New List(Of String) From {"X", " ", "X", " ", " ", "X", "X", "X", " ", " "},
            New List(Of String) From {"X", " ", "X", "X", " ", " ", " ", " ", "X", " "},
            New List(Of String) From {" ", "X", " ", " ", "X", " ", " ", "X", " ", " "},
            New List(Of String) From {" ", "X", "X", " ", "X", " ", " ", " ", " ", "X"},
            New List(Of String) From {" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "X", "X", " ", " ", "X"},
            New List(Of String) From {"X", "X", " ", "X", " ", " ", " ", "X", " ", " "},
            New List(Of String) From {" ", " ", " ", "X", "X", " ", " ", " ", "X", " "}
            }
```

Now you can add a line to end like so:

```
board.Add(New List(Of String) From {" ", "X", " ", " ", " " ... })
```

Or add a column like this:

```
For Each c As List(Of String) In board
    c.Add(" ")
Next
```